# Using chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest to match on anything in the URL?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm looking at http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html
and struggling to match the allowed urls.

This is what I want to match with:

/twitter/*

But it won't accept it, can it be done?

Comment: Have you tried `*://*/twitter/*` ?

Comment: I got it working with Regex but the Redirect URL isn't working for some reason.

I even checked to see if it hits the line and it does, it just doesn't redirect. Ideas?